# Save a price in an array to retrieve later

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to send custom signals to a Bot based on TV condition. To open a trade, I use a cross of emas condition. What I want to achieve is that, once the position is opened, dont add more margin to that position if the deviation is less than a fixed "%".
Problem comes when trying to store the vale of the price which we entered the position in order to do the calculations.
I am trying with arrays, but it seems it keeps deleting the data.. any help?

```
arr = array.new_float(0)
 
if buySignal
    array.push(arr, close)
    lab = ""
    for i = 0 to array.size(arr) - 1
        lab := lab + tostring(array.get(arr, i)) + " "
    l = label.new(bar_index, close, lab)
    label.delete(l[1])
```

This is the code I have written, but it only stores the last value where the condition where met.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the `var` keyword to declare the array so it isn't reinitialized on each new bar.

`var float[] arr = array.new_float(0)`